# Add htmlspecialchars around a variable that's between curly brackets

Tags: php

Given the below block of code I would like to include `$category_info['name']` to a `htmlspecialchars()` but there is a slight problem as the variable is included in curly brackets.

```
$data['sendCategory'] .= "
        'id': {$category_id},
        'name': '{$category_info['name']}',
        'parent': {$category_id_parent},
        'breadcrumb': [
        ";
```

I tried the following variants but they broke the code:

```
'name': '{htmlspecialchars($category_info['name'])}',
```

and

```
'name': 'htmlspecialchars({$category_info['name']})',
```

Comment: Have you also tried `'.htmlspecialchars($category_info['name']).'`

Comment: php will evaluate (interpolate) variables within double quotes, but it does not evaluate arbitrary code within quotes. So, you need to break out of the quotes or else run the variable through `htmlspecialchars` somewhere before this (wherever you set `$category_info['name']`)

Comment: `'name': '{htmlspecialchars($category_info['name'])}'` ... `'` is **not** the same as `"` : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it before that line:

```
$encoded_category_info = htmlspecialchars($category_info['name']);
$data['sendCategory'] .= "
                'id': {$category_id},
                'name': '{$encoded_category_info}',
                'parent': {$category_id_parent},
                'breadcrumb': [
                ";
```

Or if you really want it to be inline, concatenate it in:

```
$data['sendCategory'] .= "
                'id': {$category_id},
                'name': '" . htmlspecialchars($category_info['name']) . "',
                'parent': {$category_id_parent},
                'breadcrumb': [
                ";
```

Basically, you're approaching the concept of "code within code" in your strings, which can quickly make it difficult to parse and understand things.  Separate it out cleanly where possible.  Not just for the parser, but for you when you read the code later.

Comment: Thank you, David. It was a silly issue from my side as I was overthinking it and the answer was that simple. I chose to declare a new variable so I can keep the code clean.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
$data['sendCategory'] .= "
                'id': {$category_id},
                'name': '{$category_info[\'name\']}',
                'parent': {$category_id_parent},
                'breadcrumb': [
                ";
```